# Regular Expressions for titles and names

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will match anything of the form 'Mr. ABCD.', 'Mr. OSKELY.', 'Mr. ANNEUS.', 'Ms. PPHHIILLIIPPAA.', 'Mr. LEE.', etc. I'm currently using `'\b[M].\.\s[A-Z]+\.'`, but it keeps missing 'Mr. LEE.' Any suggestions? Ideally I'd also like it to match 'The GRAND POOBAH', but that's secondary.

Comment: It works for me, even with "Mr. LEE."

Comment: yes indeed it matches :)

Comment: Thanks all - the problem must be elsewhere in my code, then.

Answer (score 1):

You can try
`\b[MT][a-z\.]{2}\s*[A-Z ]+\.`

This regex match

- Ms. PPHHIILLIIPPAA.
- Mr. LEE.
- The GRAND POOBAH.
- The XXXX YYYY ZZZZ.

---

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ekarFPfO6Z5_Ajnz)

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need to use a word boundary `\b` in this case. You could just do..

```
(?:M(?:rs?|s)|The)\.?\s+[A-Z ]+\.?
```

Answer (score 0):

and if you want match The GRAND POOBAH you will need enable match case (where you use this)

```
 \b[A-Z][a-z\.]+\s[A-Z ]+\.?
```

and I am not ure if you need \b

Comment: I think that the \b was what was causing it the problem with Mr. LEE, though I don't know why. When I took it out it worked. Actually, that regex is matching way too much, but I think I can modify it.